# Is it possible to return a response DTO that matches what is expected in the Contract using IErrorHandler

Tags: c#, wcf

I want to be able to catch all unhandled exceptions and return the expected DTO but with some error information filled in. For example

```
public class CreateFooRequest
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class CreateFooResponse
{
    public Foo Created { get; set; }

    public string Error { get; set; }  // If call was successful then this will be null

    public string Detail { get; set; }
}

public interface IFooService
{
    CreateFooResponse Create(CreateFooRequest request);
}

public ErrorHandler: IErrorHandler
{
    public bool Handle(Exception ex)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
    {
        // Some how figure out that IFooService.Create was called. 
        // Inspect the method signature and see that there is an input called CreateFooRequest
        // Use reflection to initialize response objects that will replace the "Request" with "Response"
        var response = new CreateFooResponse();
        response.Error = error.GetType().Name;
        // I think i need one of the following overloads
        fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, action, response);
    }
}
```

Is doing something like this even possible? We are using NetTCP as our binding if that makes a difference.

Comment: What is the exact problem you are experiencing? WCF supports [custom error handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751439(v=vs.110).aspx) and it is quite easy to implement it.

Comment: @Sergey I cannot seem to be able to achieve what I mentioned in the pseudo code. How do I get the input arguments for the service call, figure out it was an XxxRequest so then I use reflection and create an XxxResponse object (or know that the service should have returned an XxxResponse).  Now I want to send the XxxResponse object back because that is what the client was expecting but now the XxxResponse.Status is set to something like "User Disabled". I don't want to use exceptions and faults.

Comment: I added my vision on how I would implement that. Why exactly don't you want to catch exceptions in your service methods or use fault contracts?

Comment: Understanding your "vision" what is your end goal? That is, what are you ultimately trying to achieve? What does returning an "expected DTO" accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IErrorHandler is designed to generate fault contracts. If you don't want to return a fault, you are better off taking an interceptor approach and using a the [IOperationInvoker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ioperationinvoker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension point instead.

The operation invoker is the part of the WCF framework that actually calls the service method. When you extend it, you can effectively "intercept" the call to the service. Note the Invoker does have responsibilities. You can't simply replace the WCF invoker implementation. Instead you chain them (see below).

At a high level the steps are:

1. Create an IOperationInvoker.Invoke() that implements a try/catch block. Catch the exceptions you want to be Response messages instead of FaultExceptions.
2. Create an IOperationBehavior (that's optionally also an attribute) to apply the behavior to your service.

The approach has a couple of advantages:

1. The exception is caught before WCF sees it.
2. In a IOperationBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior() you have access to the OperationDescription at the time of service start up. If you save this in the Invoker, you don't need to use reflection to capture the method's return type.
3. The IOperationBehavior.Validate() allows robust checks to ensure that the return type can actually be processed.

Below is a complete windows console application that demonstrates the approach. Paste it into Visual Studio, add the obvious assembly references, and run it.

My apologizes for the large amount of code and excessive use of base classes. I'm cutting down from actual production code.

If you want a better understanding of the IOperationInvoker extension point and what the example `InvokerBase` class is doing see [Carlos Figueira's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/05/17/wcf-extensibility-ioperationinvoker.aspx).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WcfErrorResponse
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides a base IOperationInvoker implementation that stores and passes through calls to the exisiting (old) invoker
    /// </summary>
    public abstract class InvokerBase : IOperationInvoker
    {
        private readonly IOperationInvoker m_OldInvoker;

        protected IOperationInvoker OldInvoker
        {
            get { return m_OldInvoker; }
        }

        public InvokerBase(IOperationInvoker oldInvoker)
        {
            m_OldInvoker = oldInvoker;
        }

        public virtual object[] AllocateInputs()
        {
            return OldInvoker.AllocateInputs();
        }

        public virtual object Invoke(object instance, object[] inputs, out object[] outputs)
        {
            return OldInvoker.Invoke(instance, inputs, out outputs);
        }

        public virtual IAsyncResult InvokeBegin(object instance, object[] inputs, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
        {
            return OldInvoker.InvokeBegin(instance, inputs, callback, state);
        }

        public virtual object InvokeEnd(object instance, out object[] outputs, IAsyncResult result)
        {
            return OldInvoker.InvokeEnd(instance, out outputs, result);
        }

        public virtual bool IsSynchronous
        {
            get { return OldInvoker.IsSynchronous; }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Base implementation for a Method level attribte that applies a <see cref="InvokerBase"/> inherited behavior.
    /// </summary>
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public abstract class InvokerOperationBehaviorAttribute : Attribute, IOperationBehavior
    {
        protected abstract InvokerBase CreateInvoker(IOperationInvoker oldInvoker, OperationDescription operationDescription, DispatchOperation dispatchOperation);

        public void AddBindingParameters(OperationDescription operationDescription, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        { }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, ClientOperation clientOperation)
        { }

        public virtual void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
        {
            // chain invokers.
            IOperationInvoker oldInvoker = dispatchOperation.Invoker;
            dispatchOperation.Invoker = CreateInvoker(oldInvoker, operationDescription, dispatchOperation);
        }

        public virtual void Validate(OperationDescription operationDescription)
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    public class ResponseExceptionInvoker : InvokerBase
    {
        private Type returnType;

        public ResponseExceptionInvoker(IOperationInvoker oldInvoker, OperationDescription operationDescription)
            : base(oldInvoker)
        {
            // save the return type for creating response messages
            this.returnType = operationDescription.GetReturnType();

            if (this.returnType == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The operation '" + operationDescription.SyncMethod.DeclaringType.Name + "' does not define a return type.");
            }
        }

        public override object Invoke(object instance, object[] inputs, out object[] outputs)
        {
            object returnedValue = null;
            object[] outputParams = new object[] { };
            outputs = new object[] { };

            try
            {
                returnedValue = OldInvoker.Invoke(instance, inputs, out outputParams);
                outputs = outputParams;
                return returnedValue;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Debug("ResponseExceptionInvoker() - Caught Exception. A Response Message will be returned. Message='" + ex.Message + "'");

                // there was an excpetion. Do not assign output params... their state is undefined.
                //outputs = outputParams;

                try
                {
                    // assumes the behavior only used for return types that inherit from Response, as verified by ResponseExceptionOperationBehaviorAttribute.Validate()
                    Response response = (Response)Activator.CreateInstance(this.returnType);
                    response.Success = false;
                    response.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
                    return response;
                }
                catch (Exception exCreateResponse)
                {
                    // Log that the Response couldn't be created and throw the original exception.
                    // Probably preferable to wrap and throw.
                    Logger.Error("Caught ResponseException, but unable to create the Response object. Likely indicates a bug or misconfiguration. Exception will be rethrown." + exCreateResponse.Message);
                }

                throw;
            }
        }
    }

    public class ResponseExceptionOperationBehaviorAttribute : InvokerOperationBehaviorAttribute
    {
        protected override InvokerBase CreateInvoker(IOperationInvoker oldInvoker, OperationDescription operationDescription, DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
        {
            return new ResponseExceptionInvoker(oldInvoker, operationDescription);
        }

        public override void Validate(OperationDescription operationDescription)
        {
            // validate that this attribute can be applied to the service behavior.
            Type returnType = operationDescription.GetReturnType();
            if (!typeof(Response).IsAssignableFrom(returnType))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("'" + returnType.FullName + "' does not inherit from '" + typeof(Response).FullName +
                                                    "'. ImplicitResponse behavior applied to '" + operationDescription.SyncMethod.DeclaringType.Name + "." + operationDescription.Name +
                                                    "' requires the method return type inherit from '" + typeof(Response).FullName);
            }
        }
    }

    static class OperationDescriptionExtensions
    {
        public static Type GetReturnType(this OperationDescription operationDescription)
        {
            if (operationDescription.SyncMethod == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("These behaviors have only been tested with Sychronous methods.");

            // !! Warning: This does NOT work for Asynch or Task based implementations.
            System.Reflection.MethodInfo method = operationDescription.SyncMethod ?? operationDescription.EndMethod;
            return method.ReturnType;
        }
    }

    // When not using FaultContracts, return success/fail as a part of all responses via some base class properties.
    [DataContract]
    public class Response
    {
        [DataMember]
        public bool Success { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    }

    public class ChildResponse : Response
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Foo { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Request
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ISimple
    {
        [OperationContract]
        ChildResponse Work(Request request);

        [OperationContract]
        ChildResponse Fail(Request request);
    }

    public class SimpleService : ISimple
    {
        public ChildResponse Work(Request request) {
            return new ChildResponse() { Success = true };
        }

        [ResponseExceptionOperationBehavior]
        public ChildResponse Fail(Request request)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("This method isn't done");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServiceHost simpleHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(SimpleService), new Uri("http://localhost/Simple"));
            simpleHost.Open();

            ChannelFactory<ISimple> factory = new ChannelFactory<ISimple>(simpleHost.Description.Endpoints[0]);
            ISimple proxy = factory.CreateChannel();

            Logger.Debug("Calling Work...");
            var response1 = proxy.Work(new Request() { Name = "Foo" });
            Logger.Debug("Work() returned Success=" + response1.Success + " message='" + response1.ErrorMessage + "'");

            Logger.Debug("Calling Fail...");
            var response2 = proxy.Fail(new Request() { Name = "FooBar" });
            Logger.Debug("Fail() returned Success=" + response2.Success + " message='" + response2.ErrorMessage + "'");

            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to close the host.");
            Console.ReadLine();

            ((ICommunicationObject)proxy).Shutdown();

            simpleHost.Shutdown();
        }
    }


    public static class CommunicationObjectExtensions
    {
        static public void Shutdown(this ICommunicationObject obj)
        {
            try
            {
                obj.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Shutdown exception: {0}", ex.Message);
                obj.Abort();
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Logger
    {
        public static void Debug(string message) { Console.WriteLine(message); }

        public static void Error(string message) { Console.WriteLine(message); }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Thank you. I wish I could do more than just give you one upvote and some bounty.

Answer (score 1):

In your place, I would implement this as simple as possible by using general `try/catch` block. Using custom exception handler to observe the invoked service method and create a corresponding response using reflection looks like an overkill for me.

Make your life easier:

```
public CreateFooResponse Create(CreateFooRequest request)
{
    try
    {
        // Create Foo
        var foo = CreateFoo();

        // Return successful CreateFooResponse
        return new CreateFooResponse
        {
            Created = foo,
            Error = null,
            Detail = "Created successfully"
        };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Return CreateFooResponse with an error
        return new CreateFooResponse
        {
            Created = null,
            Error = CreateError(ex),
            Detail = "Unable to create Foo."
        };
    }
}
```

A good example of using custom WCF error handler is to log the error, convert it to the `FaultContract` and return to the caller. You have a different scenario and I would suggest a different approach.

Comment: But I wanted to rather use the interceptor and write generic code because we have 100+ methods already and it is set to grow. It is quite a big API.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would like to say that it is much better to use [faultcontracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752208(v=vs.110).aspx). Below I will give an example for service GetDataUsingDataContract:

```
[OperationContract]
CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

[DataContract]
public class CompositeType 
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool BoolValue { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string StringValue { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you create a bodyWriter equivalent to a normal response:

```
public class MyBodyWriter : BodyWriter
{
    public CompositeType CompositeType { get; private set; }
    public MyBodyWriter(CompositeType composite)
        : base(false)
    {
        CompositeType = composite;
    }

    protected override void OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
    {
       writer.WriteStartElement("GetDataUsingDataContractResponse", "http://tempuri.org/");
       writer.WriteStartElement("GetDataUsingDataContractResult");
       writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "a", null, "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfService1");
       writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "i", null, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
       writer.WriteStartElement("a:BoolValue");
       writer.WriteString(CompositeType.BoolValue.ToString().ToLower());
       writer.WriteEndElement();
       writer.WriteStartElement("a:StringValue");
       writer.WriteString(CompositeType.StringValue);
       writer.WriteEndElement();
       writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
}
```

And finally, you use it in your IErrorHandler:

```
    public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
    {
        // TODO: parse error and gets response
        var response = new CompositeType {BoolValue = true, StringValue = "a"};
        fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, "http://tempuri.org/", new MyBodyWriter(response));
    }
```

I did a test and I can get a correct answer if the service throws an exception or if the service responds normally:

```
    var response1 = client.GetDataUsingDataContract(null);
    var response2 = client.GetDataUsingDataContract(new CompositeType { StringValue = "a", BoolValue = true });
```